# Qt5: how to batch process by using QProcess

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5, qprocess

I want to let QProcess run many command at a time,instead of one at a time.

```
void Route::add_route()
{
    QProcess *Add_route = new QProcess(this);
    Add_route->start("notepad",QStringList() << "interface" << "ipv4" << "set" << "interface" << "" << "metric=1");
    Add_route->start("explorer",QStringList() << "interface" << "ipv6" << "set" << "interface" << "" << "metric=1");
    Add_route->waitForFinished();
}
```

By using this,it will only run the first one.
Ps: I'm using notepad and explorer just for test
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

QProcess has a member-function `startDetached()`. Use one QProcess for every process you need to start, not one QProcess for all processes. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached

Comment: How about every start add one waitforfinished?I will replace notepad and explorer to netsh,so it will not take much time to run it.

Answer (score 0):

`QProcess` as name suggest represents single process not multiple.
So your requirement to run two processes using single `QProcess` object is faulty by design.

You have two choices:

- [QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) as markus0nm suggested in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364408/1387438)
- create multiple instances of `QProcess`, one for each process "command"

Comment: Thanks,I use the second one